# replacing strings in a ruby bash script - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I have the following `Vagrant` file:

```
require 'json'

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
path="#{current_dir}/data_bags/config/info.json"
data = JSON.parse(File.read(path))
cluster_size = data['cluster_size']
user = data['user']

$script = <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
HADOOP_HOME="/home/#{user}/hadoop"
HADOOP_CONF="$HADOOP_HOME/conf"

if [ ! -d $HADOOP_CONF ]; then
   echo "$DIR doesn't exist"
   mkdir -p $DIR
fi

cd $HADOOP_CONF 
awk '$2~/namenode/ { print $1 > "masters" } $2~/slave/ { print $1 > "slaves"}' /etc/hosts
cat slaves | \
while read CMD; do
    echo "Copying files to $CMD"
    scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no core-site.xml mapred-site.xml hdfs-site.xml #{user}@$CMD:$HADOOP_CONF
done

#$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format -force
#$HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh
#sudo chown #{user} $HADOOP_HOME/logs -R

EOF
```

let's say `user="ubuntu"` so I was expecting to replace everything by `ubuntu` but what I got was:

```
Warning: Permanently added '<ipaddress1>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
scp: /home/#{user}/hadoop/conf: No such file or directory
Warning: Permanently added '<ipaddress2>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
scp: /home/#{user}/hadoop/conf: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: why dont you use open3 instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with your heredoc syntax:

```
2.0.0-p353 :004 > a = "abc"
 => "abc"
2.0.0-p353 :005 > x = <<eof
2.0.0-p353 :006"> something with #{a}
2.0.0-p353 :007"> eof
 => "something with abc\n"
2.0.0-p353 :008 > x = <<'eof'
2.0.0-p353 :009'> something with #{a}
2.0.0-p353 :010'> eof
 => "something with \#{a}\n"
2.0.0-p353 :011 >
```

If you remove the quotes around your EOF it should work.